# Disable checkbox on dynamically created elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr

I am trying to disable checkbox elements on GPA Calculator App using jQuery

The checkbox is created dynamically when adding a new course to indicate if the student has repeated the course in order to fill his previous grade on it:

```
    if(hourSum < 21){
      $("<div class='course'>"
                       + "<div class='tdnum'>"
                       + "<span class='subNum' id='subNum" + i + "'>" + i + " </span>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='tdgrade'>"
                       + "<span class='requiredMsg' id='markReq" + i + "'>*</span>"
                       + "<input type='number' class='mark'>"
                       + "<span class='errorMessage' id='markError" + i + "'>* between 35 - 100</span>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='tdhour'>"
                       + "<span class='requiredMsg' id='shourReq" + i + "'>*</span>"
                       + "<input type='number' class='shour'>"
                       + "<span class='errorMessage' id='shourError" + i + "'>* between 1 - 3</span>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='tdrep'>"
                       + "<input id='subState" + i + "' class='repSub' type='checkbox'>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='tdpgrade'>"
                       + "<input type='number' class='rmark' id='rmark" + i + "' disabled>"
                       + "<span class='errorMessage' id='rmarkError" + i + "'>* between 35 - 100</span>"
                       + "</div>"
                       + "<div class='tddelete'>"
                       + "<span class='remove'><img src='img/delete.png'></span>"
                       + "</div>"
                   + "</div>").appendTo(".ctable").hide().fadeIn(300); // add fade effect on adding elements          
             i++;
   }
```

I need to disable this checkbox of class `.repSub` when number of passed hours = 0 and overall average = 0

```
"<input id='subState" + i + "' class='repSub' type='checkbox'>"
```

I tried this method:

```
 $(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);
```

also I tried:

```
$(".repSub").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

but both methods aren't working on dynamically created checkbox

is there any worked solution for this problem ?

Comment: And where and when are you using above methods/

Comment: Where you put this line: `$(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);`? it should be after appending the html.

Comment: Why not have the disable added while you append the elements?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani yes it's after appending the html.but I want to disable the checkbox elements only when number of passed hours = 0 and overall average = 0 
in just this particular case.

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri because i didn't want the checkbox to be disabled in general cases . it will be disabled in only one case.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e9ubveL2/1/ Can you reproduce your issue here?

Comment: Oh ok! Did you debug the code. add a break point to the disable code segment and run ` $(".repSub")` in the console. if the counter is 0 then you have your code in wrong place!

Comment: @JohnR  I put my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/e9ubveL2/7/

Comment: I want all the new created elements of checbox to be disabled after user input 0 on number of passed hours and overall average.

Comment: you want to disable the checkbox on typing 0 itself or after focusing out the input?

Comment: @JohnR on typing 0 but the important part to disable all of the new created checkbox after typing 0.

Comment: @Oghli https://jsfiddle.net/e9ubveL2/8/ Let me know your comments.

Comment: @JohnR only worked for already existing checkbox it isn't working for the new created elements.

Comment: @Oghli https://jsfiddle.net/e9ubveL2/9/ Hope this is your requirement.

Comment: @Oghli Can you please replace `$(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);` with ` console.log($(".repSub"))` and report the result?

Comment: @JohnR Thanks worked but not the way i intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a callback function to execute the code actually the elements are dynamically load on dom that's why the code is not working while you add the
    $(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);
or
    $(".repSub").attr("disabled", 'disabled');

Here is the example code i written here,
Just make some change over here

```
"+ </div>)".appendTo(".ctable").hide().fadeIn(300,function(){
$(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

I just use fadeIn callback function so it will allways work after the elem fadeIn

Please notify me if this is working or not

If it is not working you can use Promise() or done() method for do the stuff
Here is the example

```
var str = "<div id='xx'>Some content</div>";
$(str).appendTo("#qo").promise().done(function(){
$("#xx").html("Change the content");
$("#xx").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

"qo" is a div id and where i put #xx div dynamically and then after load  the content i change some content and disable the element.

Please comment.

Comment: Thanks alot. second way `.promise().done()` method worked for me.
I added my solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found fine solution to the problem after testing more than way

The only way which is worked for me is [Ankur Das](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731218/5169186) method that he mentioned in his answer

I used `.promise().done(function(){})` method with callback function after appending the elements which are dynamically added:

```
+"</div>").appendTo(".ctable").hide().fadeIn(300).promise().done(function(){
                  hour = Number($("#hrs").val());
                  avg = Number($("#avg").val());
                  if (hour === 0 && avg === 0) {
                    $(".repSub").prop("disabled", true);
                  } 
                  else {
                    $(".repSub").prop("disabled", false);
                  }
          });
```

live demo for the problem solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9ubveL2/10/